# How can display score and name in UITableView score high to low?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults

```
   name                  score

   -----                 -----    

   Abby                   34  
    b                     40 
    c                     70
    d                     20
```

my code is

```
 -(void)btnSaveScore
 {
if(!dictWinData)
    dictWinData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


scoreCardArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"ScoreCard"] mutableCopy];
if([scoreCardArray count] == 0)
{
    scoreCardArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    scorearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    playerarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
else
{
    scorearray = [scoreCardArray objectAtIndex:0];
    playerarray = [scoreCardArray objectAtIndex:1];
    [scoreCardArray removeAllObjects];
}

 //    NSMutableArray *strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strNameOFPlayer];
NSMutableArray *strScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",iTap]];

if([strNameOFPlayer length]==7)
{
[scorearray addObject:strScore];
[playerarray addObject:strNameOFPlayer];
}
 else if ([strNameOFPlayer length] == 6)
 {
[scorearray addObject:strScore];
[playerarray addObject:strNameOFPlayer];
 }
else if ([strNameOFPlayer length] == 5)
{
[scorearray addObject:strScore];
[playerarray addObject:strNameOFPlayer];
}
else if ([strNameOFPlayer length] == 4)
{
    [scorearray addObject:strScore];
[playerarray addObject:strNameOFPlayer];
}
else if ([strNameOFPlayer length] == 3)
{
    [scorearray addObject:strScore];
[playerarray addObject:strNameOFPlayer];
}
else if ([strNameOFPlayer length] == 2)
{
    [scorearray addObject:strScore];
[playerarray addObject:strNameOFPlayer];
}
else if ([strNameOFPlayer length] == 1)
{
     [scorearray addObject:strScore];
     [playerarray addObject:strNameOFPlayer];
     }

     [scoreCardArray addObject:scorearray];
     [playerarray addObject:playerarray];

     NSUserDefaults *dfltsData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     [dfltsData setObject:scoreCardArray forKey:@"ScoreCard"];
     [dfltsData synchronize];

     NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [self sortByfloatvalue:scoreCardArray array:playerarray];
     arrScores = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:0];
     arrPlayers = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:1];
     NSLog(@" %@ \n %@",scoreCardArray,playerarray);

     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                                     message:@"Score is saved."
                                                    delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
     [alert show];
     [alert release];
   }

  -(NSMutableArray *)sortByfloatvalue:(NSMutableArray *)scorearray1 array:(NSMutableArray *)playerarray1
     {
         NSMutableArray *sortedArr = [NSMutableArray array];
         for(int k=0;k<[scorearray1 count];k++)
         {
             for(int l=k+1;l<[scorearray1 count];l++)
             {
                 if([[scorearray1 objectAtIndex:k] floatValue] < [[scorearray1 objectAtIndex:l] floatValue])
                 {
                     [scorearray1 exchangeObjectAtIndex:k withObjectAtIndex:l];   
                     [playerarray1 exchangeObjectAtIndex:k withObjectAtIndex:l];
                 }
             }
         }
         [sortedArr addObject:scorearray1];
         [sortedArr addObject:playerarray1];
         return sortedArr;
     }
```

Comment: am storeing score and name?in nsuserdefaults ?? in array object that object passing to uitableview and display my name and score but problem is ....i want sort score high to low please help me ???

Comment: the above score is not sorted order please how can sort nsuserdefaults values????

Answer (score 0):

I am just posting the thing you have to consider.

See the `sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:` method in [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#) documentation.

There are also similar methods in [`NSMutableArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Please check those.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the various 'sortUsing...' methods on NSMutableArray - you should not have to implement your own sorts.

For example here is some doc on how to use 'sortUsingComparator'

sortUsingComparator:
Sorts the array using the comparison method specified by a given NSComparator Block.

```
- (void)sortUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr
```

*You use NSComparator blocks in comparison operations such as NSArray’s sortedArrayUsingComparator:, for example:*

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {

    if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```